# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while initializing class in application onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-lru-cache

I am trying to instantiate a class on my applications `onCreate` method as follows:

```
volleyQueueInstance = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Following is my `VolleySingleton` class

```
public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(30);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

But my app crashes on launch with the following stacktrace that says no class definition found for class `VolleySingleton`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides.volleyclasses.VolleySingleton$1
        at rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides.volleyclasses.VolleySingleton.<init>(VolleySingleton.java:25)
        at rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides.volleyclasses.VolleySingleton.getInstance(VolleySingleton.java:44)
        at rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides.MyApplication.instantiateVolleyQueue(MyApplication.java:35)
        at rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:31)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am fairly new to java and android and am unable to figure out why is it not able find the class. As far as I understand, It is able to find the class but the exception occurs inside the constructor where I am trying to define `mImageLoader`. I am not sure though. Any help would be really appreciated.

#### update

Ok, I tried launching the application with another device (Samsung s4) and the application works fine. But when I try it with another device (Samsung Google Nexus S) it crashes with the above stacktrace.

#### update #2

I missed some log entries in the above stacktrace, Maybe this can help figure out whats going on.

```
01-05 05:46:12.933    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides.volleyclasses.VolleySingleton$1', referenced from method rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides.volleyclasses.VolleySingleton.<init>
01-05 05:46:12.933    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9625 (Lrides/even/odd/oddorevenrides/volleyclasses/VolleySingleton$1;) in Lrides/even/odd/oddorevenrides/volleyclasses/VolleySingleton;
01-05 05:46:12.933    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001d
01-05 05:46:12.949    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfd9f at 0x1f in Lrides/even/odd/oddorevenrides/volleyclasses/VolleySingleton;.<init>
01-05 05:46:13.343    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-05 05:46:13.343    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d2a300)
01-05 05:46:14.070    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Usual this kind of exception (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`) happens when java able to find this class at compile time but on runtime it isn't accessible. I haven't experience in Android but usually `manifest.mf` file responsible for runtime dependencies. Try to google in this direction.

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly will definitely try researching this direction. Is it possible though that it works on one device but not on the other if it is a manifest issue ?

Comment: Just wild guess, if different devices has different runtime Android 5 vs Android 4 for example, and Android 4 dependencies persist but Android 5 absent it may happen, again it's wild guess.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so after hours of research finally I was able to resolve it. The problem here was the `MultiDex` support. I had partial multidex support in my app as I had

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in my build.gradle file but my application was extending the `Application` class.

Just had my application class extend [`MultiDexApplication`](http://MultiDexApplication) class and also added the following method in my application class file.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Was able to resolve it by researching towards the following log entry.

```
01-05 05:46:12.949    3029-3029/rides.even.odd.oddorevenrides D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfd9f at 0x1f in Lrides/even/odd/oddorevenrides/volleyclasses/VolleySingleton;.<init>
```

Comment: According to [Configure your app for multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle) you need to either inherit `MultiDexApplication` **or** override `attachBaseContext`.